# How can I verify a MySQL import of a database that was previously exported?

Tags: mysql

When exporting a MySQL database and then importing the MySQL database (with a new name), how can I verify that there was no corruption or data loss?

Comment: If the file was corrupted, it would be extremely unlikely to load without error.

Comment: Honestly, I have batch that are running every day dump + import with no failure since a couple of years. If it breaks, it breaks (tables are missing for example). I checked in the past for consistency by doing some count and look for max record value in different critical table. I am using innoDB when my data are critical. My 2 cents

Comment: Obviously I simplified the situation to ask a meaningful question. The question is, is there a way to check the integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the rows in each table, and make sure the counts match before and after.

Look at the first (lowest) and last (highest id) row in each table and make sure they are what you expect.

This will compute the SHA-1 hashes of the values of a text field in batches of 100 rows. There need to be `id` and `content` columns for this to work it, but you can change it to match your table.

```
  SELECT id DIV 100 AS idbatch,  
         SHA1(GROUP_CONCAT(content ORDER BY id)) as contenthash 
    FROM table
GROUP BY id DIV 100
```

If you get the same results before and after, it's a really good bet your content column has been moved over correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could dump the database and just diff the two.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. Please write more details or an example code, avoid to post short answers :)